# Using a raspberry pi 4 as a usb audio interface

Tags: usb, usb-audio, gadget, hifiberry

I want to use my raspberry pi 4 with hifiberry dac and adc as a usb audio interface for my android phone so that I can stream audio and make handsfree calls in my car. I'm having trouble finding information on how to set this up or even the proper terminology for this configuration. From what I understand, I need to configure the raspberry pi 4's usb c port as a usb gadget and use uac2 drivers to make the pi act as a usb audio interface.

ps. I do not want to use bluetooth as this is a hifi system and bluetooth is not capable of streaming audio at a sufficient bitrate.

Comment: The Pi 4's USB C plug is for powering only. Maybe you could use the Pi 0 as a gadget.

Comment: Have a look at volumio for the streaming side.  I would question your quality wish though in that you are not going to get top quality audio in a car due to the design of the car (things like seats / bodies and general engine and road noise)...  I also hope you have not just ripped CDs and are taking the raw data from HD delivery services...

Comment: "bluetooth is not capable of streaming audio at a sufficient bitrate" at which bitrate? There are many bluetooth speakers out there, providing much better audio quality than a relephone. My other concern is that you would need the PI to be a USB *device*, but it actually is a USB *host*. Maybe you should find out if it is possible to turn a PI into a USB device at all.